# Tensor product of 2 vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be V,W 2 K-vector spaces and $a \in V, b \in W$.a,b are vectors. We know that $a\otimes b=0 \in V \otimes W$. Proof that a=0 or b=0. From definition it will be a matrix with elements $a_i b_j$ and that have to be equal 0. So $a_i=0$ or $b_j=0$ ,but this not prove that a=0 or b=0.

Comment: Why not? If you say $b_j=0$ to me this means $\vec b = 0$, since you didn't specify $j$ I apply it to any $j$...

Comment: But for: $a_ib_j=0$ and $a_kb_l=0$ is still working ? 
It could be 2 vectors $a=(a_1,0,...)$   $b=(0,b_2,b_3,..)$ right? It's seems to simple to be true :)

Comment: I don't think so: an easy example with two 2-dimensional vector should illumate this: $(a_1,0)\otimes (0,b_2)=(0,a_1\cdot b_2,0,0)\neq \vec 0$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $a \otimes b = 0$. We have that for every $i$ and $j$, $a_ib_j = 0$, which is to say that either $a_i = 0$ or $b_j = 0$.

Now, suppose that $a \neq 0$.  Then, there exists some $i$ such that $a_i \neq 0$.  However, for this $i$, we still have $a_i b_j = 0$ for every $j$.  It follows that $b_j = 0$ for every $j$.

We may therefore conclude that $a \neq 0 \implies b = 0$.  Symmetrically, we may argue that $b \neq 0 \implies a = 0$.  So, if $a \otimes b = 0$, we have $a = 0$ or $b = 0$, as desired.

Comment: Martin Brandenburg lists this as a false belief in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics?page=2&tab=active#tab-top

Comment: I don't see what you're talking about @rych

Comment: You have proven that if $A \otimes B = 0$, then either $A=0$ or $B=0$ which is generally [false](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics/23640#23640). I wonder why it's true here.

Comment: @rych It holds because $V,W$ are vector spaces. I think the same holds for free modules (over commutative rings) in general.